# Python Error : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Tags: python, runtime-error

I have written a function in python that accepts a timestamp and returns the timestamp with respect to the current timezone.

**Code**

```
def datetime_from_utc_to_local(utc_datetime):
    now_timestamp = time.time()
    offset = datetime.fromtimestamp(now_timestamp) - datetime.utcfromtimestamp(now_timestamp)
    return utc_datetime + offset
```

**Error:**

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Can you please help me fix this error.

**I want this function to return the timestamp**

Comment: `utc_datetime` is supposed to be a `datetime`? The error says it is an `int`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`offset` is a [`datetime.timedelta` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta). If you need just the seconds, extract them with [`timedelta.total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds):

```
return utc_datetime + offset.total_seconds()
```

Your *function signature* however, suggests it was expecting you to feed it a `datetime.datetime()` object, in which case you shouldn't change this function, but the code that calls it. Clearly you are giving it an integer instead.